# Iterating over the string names themselves possible?

Tags: python, string, iteration

```
string1 = "content"
string2 = "some other content"
string3 = "etc."

final_string = ""
for i in range(1, x):
  final_string += string[i]
```

You get the gist.. Is this possible?
Converting *string* to a string itselves, appending a number (as a string) wouldn't work as "stringx" would be a string, thus being added to *final_string* as a string: *final_string = content*

Either way, am interested to hear any ideas - sure the "problem" can be solved in many ways, but was interested if this method is possible.

Comment: If you are naming variable with names like `string1`, `string2`, then you should be using a list and retrieving them with `string[1]`, etc. Then this problem goes away.

Comment: "sure the "problem" can be solved in many ways, but was interested if this method is possible.": as stated above I know it's possible to solve, though I wanted to know if it's doable the way I'm referencing. Anyhow, thanks for your input!

Comment: It's possible, but it involves using `eval` to execute dynamically generated code. There's no *reason* to do that, though.

Comment: `exec` is a rusty chainsaw with spikes all over the handle. Sure, if you use it very carefully, you can get the job done without hurting yourself, but it'd be a much better idea to pick a different tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `exec` for that:

```py
string1 = "content"
string2 = "some other content"
string3 = "etc."

final_string = ""
for i in range(0, 6):
  exec("final_string += string"+str(i))
```

but I would suggest you put the strings into a list as suggested in one of the answer.

Comment: `exec` is overkill; you only need `eval` to evaluate `"string" + str(i)`.

Comment: Agree. The point is that this will necessarily involve dynamically generated code, which should be avoided whenever possible.

Comment: You don't *need* `eval` or `exec` here. You can access `globals()`

Comment: Thanks for this contribution! Exactly what I was looking for. To sum things up: eval, exec or globals can be used with the same syntax mentioned above :)

Comment: @MarkMeyer Assuming `string1` et al. are in the global scope, sure.

Comment: @DoakCode please make sure to investigate  [Why using 'eval' is a bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice)

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest using a dictionary, ex:

```
my_strings = {'string1': "content", 'string3': "some other content", 'string2': "etc."}
final_string = "".join(my_strings[f'string{i}'] for i in range(1, len(my_strings) + 1))
```